# File does not exist, still success callback is getting called - promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
    function f()
    {
        console.log("aaa")
    }
    
    function g()
    {
        console.log("ddd")
    }
    
    function fileFunction()
    {                        
         console.log("In function")
         // open file
         let objPromise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
                                       {
                                            objFs.open( 'unew.js', 
                                                        'r', 
                                                        ( argError, argFD ) =>
                                                        {
                                                            resolve("done", 1000);
                                                            reject(new Error("File not found!"), 1000);
                                                        }
                                                      )
                                       }
                                     );
                                        
         objPromise.then( f, g )
 } 
    
 fileFunction()
```

The file that I have passed does not exist, still `aaa` is being printed from `f()`.

What is the way to make it call the failure callback function `g()`?

Comment: You're resolving AND rejecting the promise. The first will probably win. Conditionally resolve or reject based upon whether the file is opened sucessfully

Comment: I request you to show me an example in an answer  for how to do that or point out a document which shows such example. @Jamiec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `argError` and then return your response accordingly i.e., `resolve` or `reject` accordingly.

```
function f() {
  console.log('aaa');
}

function g(args) {
  console.log('ddd');
  //print the value that's received from `Promise`
  console.log(args);
}

function fileFunction() {
  console.log('In function');
  // open file
  let objPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    objFs.open('unew.js', 'r', (argError, argFD) => {
      if (argError) {
        return reject(new Error('File not found!'));
      }
      return resolve('done');
    });
  });

  objPromise.then(f, g);
}

fileFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `resolve` or `reject` the promise based on whether opening it was sucessful. You're currently doing both

```
let objPromise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
        {
            objFs.open( 'unew.js', 
                        'r', 
                        ( argError, argFD ) =>
                            {
                                if(argError)
                                    reject(argError);
                                else
                                    resolve("done");
                                    
                             }
                      )
         });
```

Comment: Am very thankful to you for demonstrating this basic thing.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl no problem. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You call both `resolve()` and `reject()`.

As `resolve()` is called first, it wins out, over `reject()`, because a Promise can settle a maximum of once. The `resolve()`, in this case, has no effect.

Hence, `f()` is called, not `g()`.

Try:

```
function fileFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//  ^^^^^^ important to keep fileFunction's caller informed.
        objFs.open('unew.js', 'r', (argError, argFD) => {
            if(argError) reject(argError);
            else resolve(argFD);
        });
    }).then(f, g);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can return promise from fileFunction and thenfiy it.

```
function f() {
  console.log('aaa');
}

function g(args) {
  console.log('ddd');
  //print the value that's received from `Promise`
  console.log(args);
}

function fileFunction() {
  console.log('In function');
  // open file
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    objFs.open('unew.js', 'r', (argError, argFD) => {
      if (argError) {
        return reject(new Error('File not found!'));
      }
      return resolve('done');
    });
  });
}

fileFunction().then(f, g); or fileFunction().then(f).catch(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

In callback you should check if there is error call reject function else call resolve function

```
function fileFunction() {
  console.log("In function");
  // open file
  let objPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    objFs.open("unew.js", "r", (argError, argFD) => {
      if (argError) {
        reject("File not found!");
      } else {
        resolve(argFD);
      }
    });
  });

  objPromise.then(f).catch(g); or objPromise.then(f,g)
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for downvote? Why is this answer wrong?

Comment: Aian, answers with just code and no explanatory text will frequently attract a downvotes ( it's not mine BTW :-) )

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks, but the code very clear I have added condition and called g function in catch

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I will take your advice in consideration , Thanks